# Python - Is there a shorthand for [eg]: print(f'type(var) = {type(var)}')

Tags: python, sas, string-formatting, f-string

Is there a shorthand in Python for (e.g.) `print(f'type(var) = {type(var)}')`, without having to state the object in the text and the `{.}`?

The short answer may be "no", but I had to ask!

E.g. in SAS one may use `&=` to output a macro variable and its value to the log...

```
%let macrovar = foobar;  
%put &=macrovar;
```

which returns in the log: `MACROVAR = foobar`

This is my first question, and I found it difficult to search for an answer, so apologies if it's been asked and answered.

Comment: Why "without having to state the object in the text and the {.}"? Python uses strings and `{}`-based formatting to output stuff

Comment: Just curious if it does, akin to the example I gave for another language.  Instead of having to type "%put MACROVAR = &macrovar." there is a shorthand... a bit neater is all

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed there is. As of python 3.8, you can simply type `f'{type(var)=}'`, and you will get the output you desire:

```
>>> x = {}
>>> f'{x=}'
'x={}'
>>> f'{type(x)=}'
"type(x)=<class 'dict'>"
```

Further reading:

1. The "What's New In Python 3.8" [page](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#f-strings-support-for-self-documenting-expressions-and-debugging)
2. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) for f-strings
3. The [discussion on BPO](https://bugs.python.org/issue36817) that led to this feature being implemented.

Comment: Brilliant - figured there would be! Top man